# How do OpenGL fragment shaders know what pixel to sample in a texture?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

So I've got a triangle:

[image]

And I've got a vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uViewProjection;
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoords;
varying vec2 vTextureCoords;

void main(void) {
  vTextureCoords = aTextureCoords;
  gl_Position = uViewProjection * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

And I've got a fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uMyTexture;
varying vec2 vTextureCoords;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uMyTexture, vTextureCoords);
}
```

And I feed in three sets of vertices and UVs, interleaved:

```
# x,  y,    z,   s,   t
0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.5, 1.0
-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 
1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0
```

How does the fragment shader know to draw pixel A differently from pixel B? What changes?

[image]

Comment: You fed in a texture right? Why would you expect them to be the same or are you asking how shaders work on the GPU?

Comment: @JesusRamos I'm asking how shaders work. I don't understand what's changing and who's changing it between shader passes.

Comment: Check out @genpfault's answer. I was going to say the same thing but he beat me to it :)

Comment: Check this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/14246604/187752, when OpenGL might be sampling values you are not expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it the rasterization stage of the GL pipeline [interpolates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29) `vTextureCoords` across the triangle face, running the fragment shader on each pixel with the interpolated value.

Comment: So `vTextureCoords` changes? Do all varying variables get changed somehow?

Comment: Yep, all `varying`s in the fragment shader are loaded with interpolated values.

Comment: A further explanation of this answer, along with animation, is available here: http://greggman.github.com/webgl-fundamentals/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html

Comment: Updating my link: http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html