# Attempt to fix sprite sheet pixel bleeding in OpenGL 2D causing sprite distortion

Tags: c++, opengl

While working on a project, I encountered the common problem of pixel bleeding when trying to draw subregions of my sprite sheet. This caused sort of "seams" to appear at the edges of my sprites. [You can see the issue here, on the right and top of the sprite.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjme4.png)

Doing some searching, I found others with a similar problem, and a suggested solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023400/opengl-es-texture-coordinates-slightly-off), and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/how-to-avoid-texture-bleeding-in-a-texture-atlas) for example) was to offset my texture coordinates by a bit, such as 0.5. I tried this, and it seemed to work. But I have noticed that sometimes, depending on where the sprite or camera is, I get a bit of distortion on the sprites. [Here, the left side appears to be cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahuhq.png), and [here, the bottom seems to have expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvRB3.png). (I should note, the distortion happens on all sides, I just happened to take screenshots of it happening on the bottom and left.) It may be a little difficult to see in screenshots, but it is definitely noticeable in motion.
[For reference, here is the part of the sprite sheet that is being displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6RNP.png)

Does anybody have any idea what is going on here? I didn't actually notice this issue until recently. I originally set out to resolve the pixel bleeding when I saw it occurring between my tile sprites. This new issue does not occur with them using my current half-pixel offset solution (or if it does, it's not noticeable).

Code:

Texture parameters

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Texture coordinate calculation

```
std::vector<glm::vec4> Texture2D::GetUVs(int w, int h)
{
std::vector<glm::vec4> uvs;
int rows = Width/ w;
int columns = Height / h;

for(int c = 0; c < columns; c ++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {
        float offset = 0.5;
        uvs.emplace_back(glm::vec4(float(((i) * w + offset))/Width,
                              float(((1 + i) * w - offset))/Width,
                              float(((c) * h + offset))/Height,
                              float(((1 + c) * h - offset))/Height));
    }
}
return uvs;
```

Where Width and Height are the dimensions of the sprite sheet, and w and h are the dimensions of the subregion, in this case 32 and 32.

How I pass the uvs to the shader

```
GLfloat verticies[] =
{
    uv.x, uv.w,
    uv.y, uv.z,
    uv.x, uv.z,

    uv.x, uv.w,
    uv.y, uv.w,
    uv.y, uv.z
};

this->shader.Use().SetVector2fv("uvs", 12, verticies);
```

Where uv is the uv at an index in the uvs vector that was returned above in the GetUVs function.

Vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertex; 

out vec2 TextureCoordinates;

uniform vec2 uvs[6];
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    const vec2 position [6] = vec2[]
    (
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),

        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)
    );

   TextureCoordinates = uvs[gl_VertexID];
   gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(position[gl_VertexID], 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TextureCoordinates;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D image;
uniform vec4 spriteColor;

void main()
{    
    color = vec4(spriteColor) * texture(image, TextureCoordinates);
}
```

Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated.